# Execute Script tags in ajax div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a div that get loaded via Ajax, inside the div there is a script tag that obviously will not run... on ajaxComplete I would like to search the div for script tags and execute them, how would I go about doing this... heres my code so far

HTML:

```
<div id="inside">
<script id="-locu-widget" class="locu" type="text/javascript" src="XXXXXX"></script>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){

$('#inside').find('.locu').each(function() {
eval($('#inside').html());
});

})
```

Comment: thats not going to work. firstly, i dont think you are getting `<script></script>` block within your div. Secondly, you are using `eval` wrong

Comment: you'll have to ensure that the dataType is text, meaning don't use .load. then, you'll have to parse the script tags out of the html using string manipulation or regexp, then you'll have to append the html, then execute the scripts. However, i kinda doubt the script is going to work anyway regardless of how you pull it from the string, based on it's location, i'd guess it's using document.write() which would destroy your page.